# Set upper bound for pgfplots axis width?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, width

Is there anything like

```
\pgfplotsset{
every axis/.append style={
width = 0.9\linewidth, 
max width = 4in
}}
```

Suppose I have a document with hundreds of `tikzpicture` environments, each having plots that use pgfplots `axis` environments. For simplicity of my question, none are in floats. Half of these appear individually as their own "paragraph". Half of them appear inside narrow environments, such as side by side minipages.

I'd like to use something like `width = 0.9\linewidth`, except that this would make the images which appear in their own paragraphs much too wide. So I'd like to put an upper bound on the width. Doesn't look like `max width` works as a key for this.

I am hoping to avoid setting width locally in any of the images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
width = {ifthenelse(.9\linewidth>3in,3in,.9\linewidth)}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.13,
  every axis/.append style={
    width = {ifthenelse(.9\linewidth>3in,3in,.9\linewidth)}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  \addplot{x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{minipage}[b]{5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  \addplot{x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I never would have thought that you could define width could dynamically this way.